# Error While Parsing json from a file in C++ using jsonCpp Library

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I have a JSON file somthing like that

```
[{ 
 "movie_id": 1, 
 "rating": "9.3", 
 "votes": "1,318,626", 
 "description": "Two imprisoned men bond over a number ....", 
 "title": "The Shawshank Redemption", 
 "poster": "", 
 "release_date": "14 October 1994", 
 "metascore": "80", 
 "director": "Frank Darabont", 
 "storyline": "Andy Dufresne is a young and successful ...",
 "stars": [ "Tim Robbins", "Morgan Freeman", "Bob Gunton" ], 
 "year": "1994", 
 "genre": [ "Crime", "Drama" ], 
 "gallery": [ "unknown1394846836._CB379391227_.png", ], 
 "running_time": "142min"
 },
 {...},
 {...},...]
```

I want to parse data from above file `input.json`using jsonCpp library and here is the my Code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "json/json.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
   Json::Value root;
   Json::Reader reader;

   ifstream file("input.json");
   file >> root;

   string title = root[0]["title"].asString();
   cout<<title;
   return 0;
}
```

and I used `amalgamate.py` to genrate jsoncpp.cpp and `json.h` files when I am running this code(jsoncpp.cpp) using command `g++ jsoncpp.cpp` I am getting the following error

```
/tmp/ccx18K5p.o: In function `main':
jsoncpp.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined referen to Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)'
jsoncpp.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `Json::Reader::Reader()'
jsoncpp.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `Json::operator>>   (std::istream&, Json::Value&)'
jsoncpp.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator[] (int)'
jsoncpp.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to  `Json::Value::operator[](char const*)'
jsoncpp.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `Json::Value::asString[abi:cxx11]() const'
jsoncpp.cpp:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
jsoncpp.cpp:(.text+0x12b): undefined reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What could be the problem here and how can be resovled that ?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Sounds like you did not link the library?

Comment: I think I have linked but to ensure can you please tell me the process to link library in brief ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Resolved !! I am writing answer to my question to help other 
I did not linked library properly so it gives me that error.You can link any external library in this way in c++.

1. I have two file `json/json.h` and `jsoncpp.cpp` in my current directory
2. Create a new file `main.cpp` and write down your code which used this library
3. Do not edit `jsoncpp.cpp`
4. include both `json.h` file and `jsoncpp.cpp` as shown in my updated code below.
5. then Just run `g++ main.cpp`

   ```
   #include <bits/stdc++.h>
   #include "json/json.h"
   #include "jsoncpp.cpp"
   using namespace std;
   int main(){
       Json::Value root;
       Json::Reader reader;

       ifstream file("input.json");
       file >> root;

       string title = root[0]["title"].asString();
       cout<<title<<"\n";
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Output after run `g++ main.cpp` :

   ```
   The Shawshank Redemption
   ```